# How to fetch a Map<String, List<bool>> from firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from firestore, but I struggle with this part :

[image]

Flutter throw this error :
`E/flutter (31422): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<bool>' in type cast`

To fetch firestore data, I have a fromMap function used to transform the document into an object :

```
Round.fromMap(Map snapshot)
  : round = snapshot['round'],
    isFinished = snapshot['isFinished'] ?? false,
    questions = List<Question>.from(
        snapshot['questions']?.map((x) => Question.fromMap(x))),
    playersAnswers =
        Map<String, List<bool>>.from(snapshot['playersAnswers']);
```

Do you have any tips to make this work ?

Comment: I think `playersAnswers` is a List. Try this instead `playersAnswers = List<Map<String, List<bool>>>.from(snapshot['playersAnswers']);`.

Comment: Hello @HarshTuwar ! No it's not a list, it's a map.
Each key corresponding to a user id and the value is a list of boolean

Comment: Apologies @Pierre. The only thing I can think of is `playersAnswers = Map.from(snapshot['playersAnswers'] as Map<String, List<bool>>)` because I think Map.from is considering `snapshot['playersAnswers']` as `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `Map<String, List<bool>>` but I agree that this is a "dirty" solution.

Comment: Glad I can help! Let me add it as an "official" answer :P  I'd really appreciate it if you could accept that as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is `playersAnswers = Map.from(snapshot['playersAnswers'] as Map<String, List<bool>>)` because I think `Map.from` is considering `snapshot['playersAnswers']` as `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `Map<String, List<bool>>` but I agree that this is a "dirty" solution.